# Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber-java

Error while running cucumber feature / scenario from intellij .
I have latest version of cucumber of java plugin installed (v183.4284.148)

```
 Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Unrecognized plugin: org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvm3SMFormatter
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.addPluginName(RuntimeOptions.java:171)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.parse(RuntimeOptions.java:122)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:84)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:77)
at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<init>(RuntimeOptions.java:69)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:31)
at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Following is my dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.27'
compile group: 'org.glassfish', name: 'javax.json', version: '1.1.2'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject', name: 'jersey-hk2', version: '2.27'
compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path-assert', version: '2.4.0'
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '25.0-jre'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: '4.2.0'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '4.2.0'
compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-all', version: '1.3'
compile group: 'uk.sponte.automation', name: 'selenium-pom', version: '3.0.12'
compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.11'
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '4.2.0'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.25'
compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.6.3'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.+'
testCompile group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '3.1.2'
```

}

This was working fine until 20 Dec 2018 .Tried reinstalling intellij ,reinstalling cucumber for java plugins ,using different versions of cucumber-java8 and cucumber-junit ,Nothing helped

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: This sounds like a possible issue with the plugin. You might try installing an older version of the plugin, or downgrading your Cucumber version (if you recently upgraded it). You can also check Jetbrains YouTrack for known issues with the plugin (or report your issue if needed).